# How to write a SPARQL query that asks for all the triples with the same subject/predicate/object?

Tags: sparql

Suppose my data set contains the following triples:

```
a hasName "Alice"

b hasName "Bob"

...
```

I want to find out the people who have the same name. I have no idea how to write this query. And I'm not sure if I could query this in SPARQL.

Comment: Sharing the object variable should be quite obvious if you're asking for triples with the same object: `select ?s1 ?s2 {?s1 :hasName ?name . ?s2 :hasName ?name . FILTER(?s1 > ?s2)}` Note, this returns pairs of individuals.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the details provided. Your sample data is entirely invalid RDF. I'd suggest you start by building a valid sample dataset that includes data of the sort you want to query for, putting it in an RDF store, and then trying some SPARQL queries to see if you get the results you want. @AKSW has provided a more-than-substantial hint.